# createLink not working in (mail) templates?

Tags: email, templates, grails, hyperlink

I have a Controller action and sending a mail in it with something like:

```
mailService.sendMail {
    ...
    g.render(template: "mailtemplate")
}
```

in this template file is called `_mailtemplate.gsp` I use

```
<a href="<g:createLink controller="servicecontroller" action="confirm"/>">linktext</a>
```

But the output is `http://action` ... that's it! I would expect to have `http://www.example.com/action`. If I use the same `createLink` tag in a gsp which is not a template it's working (by the way, email is working fine and all the other stuff in this template is rendered well).

Have you any suggestions on that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you need absolute link:

```
<a href="<g:createLink controller="servicecontroller" action="confirm" absolute="true"/>">linktext</a>
```

Btw, you can also use `${}` syntax there, like:

```
<a href="${g.createLink(controller: "servicecontroller", action: "confirm", absolute: true)}">linktext</a>
```

Comment: oh I forgot to write, this is probably the solution but in this case I must specify a serverURL in config file, but I want it dynamically, you know. I can not imagine why the createLink is not working in templates?! :-(

Comment: It's working. I does everything correctly. You've asked for relative url (by default) - you have relative url. But for your email client - it will be relative to email. Not original websites (email client even dont't know that this email was from an website)

Comment: btw: you do not need *g* for the namespace `g`: `${create...}`.

Comment: hmmm... now I figured out some new problems. I don't want to use the absolute:true argument. Because that must work that a URL can be relative to the current path... I put the createLink function in a normal GSP-file, I got the same "unexpected" URL, only "/servicecontroller/confirm" - nothing else. That's really strange :-(

Comment: Why it's unexpected? You're making a non-absolute url, and `/servicecontroller/confirm` is non-absolute urs, relative to your app.

Comment: Why you don't want `absolute:true`?

Comment: Yes, but how do you invoke `createLink()` programmatically from the controller if you don't want to use a template for your message content?

Comment: just use `g.createLink(...)` in your controller

Answer (score 1):

> **QUOTE:**  I must specify a serverURL in config file, but I want it dynamically

You can probably do as such:

**config.groovy:**

```
environments {
    development {
        grails.serverURL = "http://localhost:8080"
    }
    production {
        grails.serverURL = "http://www.mywebsite.com"
    }
}
```

**Then in your service sending the email:**

```
    import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ConfigurationHolder

    def baseURL = ConfigurationHolder.config.grails.serverURL

    mailService.sendMail {
    ...
    g.render(template: "mailtemplate", model:['baseURL':baseURL])
    }
```

**And at last in your link:**

```
 <a href="<g:createLink controller="servicecontroller" action="confirm" base="${baseURL}"/>">linktext</a>
```

I hope this helps

Comment: hmmm... now I figured out some new problems. I don't want to use the absolute:true- or the baseURL-argument. Because that must work that a URL can be relative to the current path... Or I'm wrong? I put the createLink function in a normal GSP-file, I got the same "unexpected" URL, only "/servicecontroller/confirm" - nothing else. That's really strange :-(